# seeding multiple models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created three model, `Task` `Detail` and `Record`.

When display my view on the browser, everything related to `Detail` disappear while things related `Task` and `Record` remains normal.

These are my models in app/models

```
class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record
  belongs_to :task
end
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :details
end
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :details
end
```

db/migrate

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :cell
      t.boolean :done
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
class CreateDetails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :details do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :valve
      t.string :cell
      t.string :description
      t.boolean :done
      t.integer :order
      t.references :task
      t.references :record
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
class CreateRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :records do |t|
      t.string :cell
      t.string :valve
      t.string :state
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrate/seeds.rb

```
r1 = Record.create(cell: "cell1", valve: "A", state: "N/A")
r2 = Record.create(cell: "cell1", valve: "B", state: "N/A")
r3 = Record.create(cell: "cell2", valve: "C", state: "N/A")
r4 = Record.create(cell: "cell2", valve: "D", state: "N/A")

t1 = Task.create(title: "Task1", cell: "cell1", done: false)
Detail.create(title: "Detail1", description: "This is detail1.1", order: 1, 
valve: "A", task_id: t1.id, done: false, cell: "cell1", record_id: r1.id)
Detail.create(title: "Detail2", description: "This is detail2.1", order: 2, 
valve: "B", task_id: t1.id, done: false, cell: "cell1", record_id: r2.id)
t2 = Task.create(title: "Task2", cell: "cell2", done: false)
Detail.create(title: "Detail3", description: "This is detail3", order: 1, 
valve: "C", task_id: t2.id, done: false, cell: "cell2", record_id: r3.id)
Detail.create(title: "Detail4", description: "This is detail4", order: 2, 
valve: "D", task_id: t2.id, done: false, cell: "cell2", record_id: r4.id)
t3 = Task.create(title: "Task3", cell: "cell1", done: false)
Detail.create(title: "Detail5", description: "This is detail5", order: 1, 
valve: "A", task_id: t3.id, done: false, cell: "cell1", record_id: r1.id)
Detail.create(title: "Detail6", description: "This is detail6", order: 2, 
valve: "B", task_id: t3.id, done: false, cell: "cell1", record_id: r2.id) 
t4 = Task.create(title: "Task4", cell: "cell2", done: false)
Detail.create(title: "Detail7", description: "This is detail7", order: 1, 
valve: "C", task_id: t4.id, done: false, cell: "cell2", record_id: r3.id)
Detail.create(title: "Detail8", description: "This is detail8", order: 2, 
valve: "D", task_id: t4.id, done: false, cell: "cell2", record_id: r4.id)
```

These are my controllers

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def show
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @details = @task.details
  end
end

class DetailsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @details = Detail.all
  end
  def show
    @detail = Detail.find(params[:id])
    @task = @detail.task
    @details = @task.details
    next_order = @detail.order + 1
    @details.each do |d|
      if d.order = next_order
        @next_detail = d
      end
    end
  end
 end

class RecordsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @records = Record.all
  end
  def show
    @record = Record.find(params[:id])
    @details = @record.details
  end
  def edit
    @record = Record.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @record = Record.find(params[:id])
    if @record.update_attributes(record_params)
      redirect_to("/records")
      else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
  def record_params
    params.require(:record).permit(:state)
  end
end
```

these are my views

details/index.html.erb

```
<div class="tasklist">
  <h2>TaskList</h2>
    <% @details.each do |d| %>
      <div class="tasks">
        <%= link_to d.title, detail_path(d) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

details/show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @detail.title %></h1>
<p><%= @detail.description %></p>
<%= link_to "back", task_path(@task) %>
<%= link_to "next", detail_path(@next_detail) %>
```

tasks/show.html.erb

```
<h2><%= @task.title %></h2>

<table>
    <tbody>
      <% @details.each do |d| %>
        <tr>
          <th><%= d.order %></th>
          <td><%= link_to d.title, detail_path(d) %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: What's in your controller and view?

Comment: Just updated that above.

Comment: Did you run the seed file with `bin/rake db:seed`?

Comment: Yes, i did that. All other contents in the seed could be shown.

Comment: Did you verify it by running `Detail.all` in the console? In seed files you should use the bang method `.create!` which will raise an error if the record is invalid. Otherwise it will just silently fail.

Comment: You can clean the seeds file up at the same time by iterating with `('A'..'D').each_with_index.map do |letter, index|; end`

Comment: I just tried to run `Detail.all` in the console and it gives `#ActiveRecord::Relation []`